# WPF dynamic data display chart - label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, Includes Dynamic Data Display. I'm trying to adding on the chart a **DYNAMIC** label or textblock. I have been success to add a textblock on the **grid** but it move with the chart (I want it on the chart on specific point- not on the screen).
My adding textBlock :

```
            TextBlock LenghtText = new TextBlock();
            LenghtText.Margin = new Thickness(180, 50, 0, 0);
            LenghtText.Text = lengthLine + "";
            LenghtText.Width = 50;
            myGrid.Children.Add(LenghtText);
            // plotter.Children.Add(LenghtText); //--> If i try this line it error that LenghtText doesn't children of a IPlotterElement
```

Comment: I am having problems understanding what the problem is. Can you try to clarify what do you expect the TextBlock to do and what is actually doing?

Comment: I have a map on the chart plotter. I want a textbox that stay on the map - chart. than when i wheel the mouse into it or move right\left it will be stay in the point on the map. Now it move with me, I mean that the textblock is on the screen/WPF grid not on the plotter.